# To look for a simple way to extract matched parts of strings from an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I want to extract  matched parts of strings --digital part from an array
`array("HK00003.Day","HK00005.Day")`.

```
<?php
$arr=array("HK00003.Day","HK00005.Day");
$result= array();
foreach ($arr as $item){
    preg_match('/[0-9]+/',$item,$match);
    array_push($result,$match[0]);
}
```

It can get the result :`00003`  `00005`,it seems tedious,preg_grep seems simple but the result is not what i want .

```
preg_grep('/[0-9]+/',$arr);
```

The output is "HK00003.Day","HK00005.Day", not `00003`  `00005`,
is there more simple way to get the job done?

Comment: Have to print_r($result) its giving perfect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, not tedious at all. If you want a one-liner you can try something like this (remove everything that's not a digit):

```
array_push($result, preg_replace("~[^0-9]~", "", $item));
```

Comment: Think for your encourage，i need it most.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Here I just get rid off every character in your array which isn't a number with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php))

```
<?php

    $arr = ["HK00003.Day", "HK00005.Day"];
    $result = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $arr);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 00003 [1] => 00005 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) (which already uses `preg_replace` and does not require additional callback functions) to replace the each entry in the array with the number inside:

```
<?php
   $arr = array("HK00003.Day","HK00005.Day");
   $matches = preg_filter('/^.*?([0-9]+).*/', '$1',$arr);
   print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output of a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYnZDcjJKNGdDNXM):

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [0] => 00003                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    [1] => 00005                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
)
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_grep  return array entries that match the pattern！ Therefore, it returns an array of entry rather than the matching string

try below:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/',implode('-',$arr),$result);
```